# Mariadb / Mysql BUG? : group by `master` in subquery

Tags: mariadb, reserved-words

I have 2 tables:

**sales:**

| id | invoice | valid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IV001 | Y |

**payment:**

| id | master | amount | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 100 | 200 | 100 |
| 111 | 100 | 300 | 100 |
| 112 | 101 | 400 | 101 |

Then I made a query:

`select master, sum(amount) amount from payment group by master`

and give result as expected

| master | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 500 |
| 101 | 400 |

But when I run following query:

`` select s.id, s.invoice, p.amount from sales s join (select `master`, sum(amount) amount from payment group by `master`) p on p.`master`=s.id ``

I got wrong result like this

| id | invoice | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IV001 | 900 (should be 500) |

But, if I use column `test` as group column, result will be ok.
I run this query:
`select s.id, s.invoice, p.amount from sales s join (select test, sum(amount) amount from payment group by test) p on p.test=s.id`
and everything looked as expected.

I guess this related to column `master` which is reserved word, and I used backtick (`) already.

My qustion is: **If I am still want to use `master` as colum name, how to solve this? or is it a Mariadb / Mysql bug ?**

(I run Mariadb version 10.3 & 10.5 on Ubuntu 21.04)

**EDIT**

Please watch this video: https://youtu.be/e2EEin1mf-E

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When I correct the second query to "on p.`master` = s.id" rather than = m.id... works for me (total 500).  When I try the statement you indicated, I get an error about unknown column 'm.id'  If that statement was accepted as written, it is definitely a bug.  What version of mySQL are you running?  (I don't recall master being a reserved word.  With MySQL 8.0 I get no error at all with or without quotes.

Comment: Ooops, sorry my mistake about "on p.master = m.id", it must be "on p.master = s.id" (edited already).

I am using Mariadb ver 10.3, I got the strange result either on my local server and also on my hosting provider that use a same version of Mariadb.

Comment: Also I run Mariadb ver 10.5 on Ubuntu 21.04 it give a same (wrong) result.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=363e662aaa2c14572c0845f191d1cff7

Comment: Data type of column id and master are varchar not integer. I tried using @Akina code works as expected. But my data supplied by php code.
I try modify query with "on trim(p.master)=s.id" and the result was ok.

I also try `select * from payment where master=trim(master)` all data displayed, means that theris no space in column master. But why in group by containing string? or may be I am wrong???

I am still don't understand why it happen.

Comment: *Data type of column id and master are varchar not integer.* It affects to nothing. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bdcb9e187c386f45d72fbb595f4ac84f Edit the fiddle, use your structures and data, and reproduce your problem in it.

Comment: @Akina
Please watch this video:
I believe that actually there is a proble on mariadb.
This not only happen on my local server but also on remote public server.

https://youtu.be/e2EEin1mf-E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Mariadb 10.3.29, 10.4.19, 10.5.10 which has now been fixed but not yet released. We came across the same issue and had to roll back to 10.4.18.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25714

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Simon, this is a bug affecting Mariadb 10.3.29, 10.4.19, 10.5.10

As a workaround (tested in 10.3.29) you can apply the following setting in your cnf file [mysqld] section

```
optimizer_switch='split_materialized=off'
```

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25725

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25714

Comment: I've found that workaround in this discussion and I tested in 10.3.29, I'm going to update my post https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25725

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with utf8mb4:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26337

check:
character_set_server=utf8mb4
in your .conf